# tkinter callback method not defined global name not defined

Tags: python, class, tkinter, callback

I would like to know why the methods `SavePVParms` `Close` and `ApplyGraph` are not defined when I call them through the buttons.  I know that if I put them inside `__init__` they will work and my problem is solved but I don't understand why it wouldn't work the way it is. I tried to look for this question and found this [Python Class: Global/Local variable name not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629910/python-class-global-local-variable-name-not-defined) and this [Python says global name not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321850/python-says-global-name-not-defined) but forgive me if I can't understand the answer there. Could you help me understand why?
Background: This class is a top level window that popups when I press a button in the root window (here i am just showing you guys the toplevel window directly). It is supposed to pass a dictionary of all the entries when I save it (not yet implemented). **Additionally (but not required to answer if you don't want to) is this an adequate style of coding in OOP? (less than 1 week learning tkinter and moving from precedural python to OOP python).

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
class PVDialog(tk.Toplevel):

    def SavePVParms(self):
        print "saved"
        self.destroy()

    def Close(self):
        self.destroy()

    def ApplyGraph(self):
        print 'applied'

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        print parent
        self.title('PV Parameters Configuration')
        self.geometry('800x480')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=8)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=2)

    # ====== FRAMES =======

        lb1Frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Electric Properties')
        lb1Frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns', pady=(15, 2), padx=(30,10))

        AdvFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='Thermal Properties')
        AdvFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ewns', pady=5, padx=(30,10))

        pcurveFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text='PV Curves')
        pcurveFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ewns', padx=(0,30), pady=(15,5),rowspan=2)

        ctrlFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        ctrlFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ens', padx=20, pady=(2, 20))

    # ======== PARAMETER INPUT DATA FRAME ============= #

        labelName = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Name', anchor='w')
        labelCellType = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Cell Type', anchor='w')
        labelPower = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Rated Power [W]', anchor='w')
        labelOV = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Open Voltage [V]', anchor='w')
        labelSCC = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Short-circuit Current [A]', anchor='w')
        labelMPC = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Maximum Point Current [I]', anchor='w')
        labelMPV = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text="Maximum point Voltage [V]", anchor='w')
        labelSeries = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Cells in series', anchor='w')
        labelPallel = tk.Label(lb1Frame, text='Cells in parallel', anchor='w')
        labelNOCT = tk.Label(AdvFrame, text='NOCT', anchor='w')
        labelThC = tk.Label(AdvFrame, text='Current T factor [%/K]', anchor='w')
        labelThV = tk.Label(AdvFrame, text='Voltage T factor [%/K]', anchor='w')
        labelThP = tk.Label(AdvFrame, text='Power T factor [%/K]', anchor='w')

        labelName.grid(row=0, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelCellType.grid(row=1, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelPower.grid(row=2, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelOV.grid(row=3, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelSCC.grid(row=4, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelMPC.grid(row=5, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelMPV.grid(row=6, sticky='ew', padx=10, pady=2)
        labelSeries.grid(row=7, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelPallel.grid(row=8, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelNOCT.grid(row=9 , sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelThC.grid(row=10, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelThV.grid(row=11, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)
        labelThP.grid(row=12, sticky='ew', padx=10,  pady=2)

        entryName = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame, show='Default')
        entryCellType = ttk.Combobox(lb1Frame)
        entryPower = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entryOV = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entrySCC = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entryMPC = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entryMPV = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entrySeries = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entryPallel = ttk.Entry(lb1Frame)
        entryNOCT = ttk.Entry(AdvFrame, width=23)
        entryThC = ttk.Entry(AdvFrame, width=23)
        entryThV = ttk.Entry(AdvFrame, width=23)
        entryThP = ttk.Entry(AdvFrame, width=23)

        entryName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryCellType.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryPower.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryOV.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entrySCC.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryMPC.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryMPV.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entrySeries.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryPallel.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky='ew')
        entryNOCT.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='w', padx=(26,0))
        entryThC.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky='w', padx=(26,0))
        entryThV.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w', padx=(26,0))
        entryThP.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky='w', padx=(26,0))

    # ==== BUTTON COMANDS ======
        saveBttn = ttk.Button(ctrlFrame, text='Save', command=SavePVParms)
        closBttn = ttk.Button(ctrlFrame, text='Cancel', command=Close)
        applyBttn = ttk.Button(ctrlFrame, text='Apply', command=ApplyGraph)
        saveBttn.grid()
        closBttn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
        applyBttn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 10))

# ======== RUNNIG THE CLIENT ============
root = tk.Tk()
dialog = PVDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Update: As I was making about to submit this question, I remembered that `__init__` is the first thing that is read and executed in the Class, so that's why the are defined if I put them in `__init__`. I still don't understand why python can't call them if they are outside `__init__` doesn't python read the whole class? how can I call then `self.method` that is outside of `__init__` then?. Thanks!

Comment: Does this code accurately reflect your actual code? The indentation looks incorrect.

Comment: fixed with correct indentation!

Answer (score 0):

`SavePVParms`, `Close`, `ApplyGraph` methods are belong to your class, so you need to use `self.` to tell interpreter that, you want to use methods from your class.

```
saveBttn = ttk.Button(..., command=self.SavePVParms)
```

For coding standarts, you should check [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) but as long as you are consistent with your style, it shouldn't matter that much.

Comment: Would there be any advantage or difference between having those methods as class methods or as instance methods? Currently I put them as __init__ instance methods just because; since I don't know. @Lafexlos

Comment: I think you should read [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods). It explains much better than I can.